# Using RestSharp to get header value from HttpResponseMessage in web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm having some trouble getting a token from a HttpResponseMessage using RestSharp. Here is my API controller code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create(long id)
{
    var token = _tokenCreator.CreateToken(id);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Headers.Add("Token", token);
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return response;
}
```

This is generating the token like I want, and creating the response pictured below. When I call the method with Postman, this is the body of the response that I receive. This is the same result I get if I look at the Content property of the response in my code that sends the request.

[Picture of response body.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVBGt.png)

There is clearly a header section there, but it's not being recognized by RestSharp in my calling code.

```
public string CreateToken(long id)
{
    var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
    {
        Resource = "tokencreator/create"
    }
    request.AddQueryParameter("id", id.ToString());

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var headers = response.Headers.ToList();

    // Here is what I want to do, but does not return a result
    var tokenHeader = headers.Find(x => x.Name == "Token");
    if(tokenHeader != null)
    {
        return tokenHeader.Value.ToString();
    }

    return "no token";
}
```

If I loop through and print the response's headers, these are the results:

- Transfer-Encoding chunked
- X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?QzpccHJvamVjdHNcYXBpXEVudGl0bGVtZW50QWNjZXNzXHRva2VuY3JlYXRvclxjcmVhdGU=?=
- Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
- Date Mon, 03 Apr 2017 16:00:18 GMT
- Server Kestrel
- X-Powered-By ASP.NET

The "Token" header I added in the controller to the response is not there. Is there a simple way to access the "header" section that is appearing in the body of the response?

Edit: Attaching a picture of the "Headers" section of the response from Postman. There is no "Token" header. Any idea why the `response.Headers.Add("Token", token)` method does not add the header, or am I misunderstanding headers completely?

[Picture of headers in Postman response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PAUE.png)

Comment: You haven't posted the headers picture (with content) from your Postman. It seems like that there is no "Token" header once in the Header section from the picture there are 6 headers and the response headers' print also lists 6 headers. I believe that the "Token" header is not being returned.

Comment: @dime2lo I edited the question to include the picture. It appears the "header" is being added only to the body and not the actual header of the request. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @dime2lo so this is a hacky workaround that I got to work. I changed the return type of the Create method to `HttpResponse`, and added the header to the Response property of the ControllerBase. Then manually set the status code, and it is working as intended. I have not seen this usage elsewhere and would still like to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I should have specified that this was a .NET Core application. To fix the problem, I had to go to the `Startup.cs` file and add the following to the `ConfigureServices` method:

Change `services.AddMvc();` to `services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();`

You will need the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim, which allows compatibility with the old Web Api 2 way.

Comment: What  should i do if i am not in .Net core applicatio,. I am doing WEB API 2.0 development. And I am facing same issue ?